# Energy stored in the curvature of spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, energy-conservation, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Lets assume there are particles with mass. If the mass is big enough, they will accelerate toward the center of mass. Thus the particles gain kinetic energy and hence the total mass gets bigger. Since the radius of particle system decreases and the total mass increases, the curvature of spacetime will grow. So what I want to ask is,

1. Does curvature of spacetime stores energy?
2. If does, is the energy density positive or negative?

I guess that **IF** the curvature stores energy, it has to be negative for the energy conservation law. But by energy condition, negative energy is forbidden. What is the key to solve this problem?

**EDIT: Each particle is stationary at initial condition and the frame is center of energy frame so that every particle gains kinetic energy.**

Comment: First:  Each particle gains kinetic energy in some frames and loses it in others...

Comment: The frame is center of energy frame and each particle is stationary at initial condition. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Before the question can be answered, a definition of energy needs to be given, along with a theorem saying that it's conserved. The usual definition (based on Noether's theorem) fails when we try to apply it to the geometry of spacetime itself, because instead of getting a conservation law, we get the trivial and useless result that the "total energy" is always identically zero, whether or not the equations of motion are satisfied. Would you be satisfied by an answer that explains this and/or explains what kinds of alternate definitions of "energy" have been considered?

Comment: Oh yes, please. I would appreciate that.